How do I verify web apps so that the can authenticate against Microsoft accounts?
We have a web application that's built using Django DRF on the backend and React on the Front end. It's currently hosted on AWS. It's a B2B application and clients get their own subdomains (e.g. client.ourproduct.com). The flow starts with a login. We currently allow Microsoft and Google SSOs to make onboarding smoother.
When using Microsoft SSO, it would display our app as "unverified" but the client didn't have an issue with this and so things were okay. They changed their IT policy to disallow this and now, they can't login with MS SSO and here's where my problems start.
I've been trying to look through the Azure documentation to get this fixed and they require (as far as I understand) for us to sign in with a Microsoft Partner Account (rather than a personal account) and then create a Microsoft Partner Network (MPN) id which we can use to verify our app and then publish it. However, we've hit numerous snags here. Some of them are - the account which we registered with on Azure is not a partner account and it can't be converted into one. When we did register with a new account to work around this, we were not able to link our company to this because it's already connected to the previous (personal) account. WE raised a few cases in the support center but they're all downgraded.
I want to be clear that I'm not asking for Microsoft Support but I want to know if someone else has done this and if so, what exactly are the steps that one needs to do to prevent this unverified banner appearing on my app.
I have included a screenshot of the error with the client specific parts blurred out and the "unverified" tag marked in red.


Could you confirm whether you added custom domain and verified it or not? Make sure to make that custom domain as Primary domain. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1465087/app-registration-is-showing-un-verified
